# Block cursor follows mouse and distorts render in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, mouse

I sometimes get a block that renders next to the mouse and distorts that portion of the screen. Logging out and logging back in sometimes fixes the issue. I have more that one user and most times are logged in as both. This issues tends to display for one user and not for the other at times.

The attached image shows the cursor, which is sometimes misplaced a few millimeters from the mouse, together with the contents of the block.

I've tried updating my software including my proprietary Nvidia drivers to no avail.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a combination of problems with the nvidia drivers and xorg. 
What worked for me was switching the driver and the window manager. I switched to the **Nouveau** driver. 
This can be found in

`Software & Updates -> the Additional Drivers -> Nouveau.`

I tried different window managers and the one that worked for me was **Xfce**.

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

Upgrade, update and reboot.

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get update
reboot
```

At log on click on the Ubuntu button or click down on the option list next to the log on prompt to select **Xfce**.

Comment: Changing Desktop Environment is is not really a solution to that problem. It's like throw away your computer and your problem is gone...